# Where to find (install) Kotlin cinterop tool on Mac

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native, cinterop

I would like to try to build Kotlin/Native project with dependencies on some library.
As documentation explains, I need to create def file (which I was already created) and run `cinterop` tool.

However, I wasn't able to find this tool on my Mac and curious how this could be installed.

Can you please give me some advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly advise you to use [Gradle + Kotlin MPP plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#cinterop-support). Not only it will provide `cinterop` support, but it will ease further development, testing, and multiplatform support. It works on any OS, of course.

If you need an example, here is the official one for the cURL library: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/samples/libcurl/build.gradle.kts. Note the `cinterops` block under `compilations["main"]`.

The nice thing about Kotlin MPP plugin is that it actually allows you to play with the Kotlin/Native tools directly. It will download the tools specifically for your platform automatically on the first run and place them in `~/.konan` directory. So if you really want to use `cinterop` tool from CLI you'll be able to find it there: `~/.konan/kotlin-native-macos-1.3.61/bin/cinterop`. `klib` and `kotlinc` are there as well.

Comment: Link is dead: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/samples/libcurl/build.gradle.kts thus answer is at least partly useless. Please always provide a code example along with your link.